# In power shell, I'm trying to convert some plain text input to a csv format

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a csv file with data taken from a PDF file.
Why? The bank has changed their web page and export of statements is in PDF only. My finance application requires the data in the form of a CSV file.
Because of security, I do not want to use any cloud service where I upload my pdf and they will convert it to a csv.
In PowerShell, I can get a text file as shown below after I cut/paste data into a text file:

The header should look like:
"Date","Description"."Money out"."Money in"."Borrowings"
My current input file (called vertical file) looks like below:

```
Date,
Description,
Money out,
Money in,
Borrowings,
01 Feb 2024,
CDN Bank 1,
1601.87,
3490.43 CR,
01 Feb 2024,
Life Ins,
372.23,
3118.20 CR,
01 Feb 2024,
Interac e-Transfer Receive,
250.00,
3368.20 CR,
01 Feb 2024,
Water company,
33.84,
3334.36 CR,
```

I need it to look like:
Note: The date 01 Feb 2024 should be the start of each line.

```
"Date","Description","Money out","Money in","Borrowings"
"01 Feb 2024","CDN Bank 1","1601.87","3490.43 CR"
"01 Feb 2024","Life Ins"."372.23","3118.20 CR"
"01 Feb 2024","Interac e-Transfer Receive","250.00","3368.20 CR"
"01 Feb 2024","Water company","33.84","3334.36 CR"
```

I copy/pasted data from the PDF file into a Notepad++ file and ran the following code to delete data I did not need. The code to delete data I did not need is: Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'James|CDNBnk|number|continued'
This is to get rid of any line that contains James,CDNBnk,Number and continued as that data is not relevant to the data I need.
And Yes, I need to figure out an extra blank line in each row because there is always a blank beneath money in OR money out. So, you are correct. If the header has 5 elements then so should the data.

```
 ``# Specify the input and output file paths
 $inputFile = "C:\Users\J\Downloads\input\VerticalFile.txt"
 $outputFile = "C:\Users\J\Downloads\Output\File.txt"

# Read the content of the input file
$lines = Get-Content $inputFile

# Append a comma to the end of each line and filter out the unwanted lines
$modifiedLines = $lines | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '[,$]', '' } | ForEach-Object { $_ + ","    
} | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'James|CDNBnk|number|continued' }

# Write the modified content to the output file
$modifiedLines | Set-Content -Path $outputFile

# Display a message indicating successful completion
Write-Host "Commas added to each line and unwanted lines removed. Output written to 
$outputFile".`
`
```

The results are shown as the vertical file above.

The second read of the file needed to create each line that started with a data (01 Feb 2024)

The code I tried and fails with: "Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string."

```
``# Specify the input and output file paths
$inputFile = "C:\Users\J\Downloads\Output\Filea.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\Users\J\Downloads\Output\File2.txt"

# Read the content of the input file
$lines = Get-Content $inputFile

# Initialize an empty array to store the combined lines and create the header
$combinedLines = @("")

# Define an array of shortform months
$months = "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"

# Loop through each line in the input file
foreach ($line in $lines) {
# Split the line by comma and store the fields in an array
$fields = $line -split ","
# Check if the first field contains a shortform month
if ($months -contains $fields[0].Substring(0,5)) {
# If yes, add the line to the combined lines array
$combinedLines += $line
} else {
# If not, append the line to the last element of the combined lines array
$combinedLines[-1] += $line
 }
}


# Write the combined lines to the output file
$combinedLines | Set-Content -Path $outputFile

# Display a message indicating successful completion
Write-Host "Lines combined by date. Output written to $outputFile"`
```

The output of the above code is $combinedLines which is written to the Outputfile:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $combinedLines
Description,Money out,Money in,Borrowings,01 Feb 2024,CDN Bank 1,1601.87,3490.43 CR,01 Feb 2024,Life Ins,372.23,3118.20 CR,01 Feb 2024,Interac e-Transfer
Receive,250.00,3368.20 CR,01 Feb 2024,Water company,33.84,3334.36 CR,

Comment: Your CSV file has 5 header columns but only 4 cells in each row - how are they supposed to align?

Comment: You also seem to filter out lines with `-notmatch 'James|CDNBnk|number|continued'` but in the question you make no mention of that. Please [edit] your question and give us a better example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.txt'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'
$headerRowsCount = 5
$dataRows = 4
$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::New($inputFilename)

$headerRows = @()
$rowCount = 0;
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
   if($rowCount -lt $headerRowsCount)
   {
      $headerRows += $line.Trim(@(" ", ","))
   }
   else `
   {
      if($rowCount -eq $headerRowsCount) {$itemCount = 0}
      $index = $itemCount % $dataRows
      if(($index) -eq 0) {$newRow = [pscustomobject]@{} }
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $headerRows[$index] -NotePropertyValue $line.Trim(@(" ", ","))

      if($index -eq 3) { $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $headerRows[4] -NotePropertyValue ($newRow."Money in".Split(' ')[0] - $newRow."Money out")}

      $itemCount++
      if($index -eq 0) {$table.Add($newRow) | out-null}
   }
   $rowCount++
}
$table | Format-Table

$table | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Here is the results

```
Date        Description                Money out Money in   Borrowings
----        -----------                --------- --------   ----------
01 Feb 2024 CDN Bank 1                 1601.87   3490.43 CR    1888.56
01 Feb 2024 Life Ins                   372.23    3118.20 CR    2745.97
01 Feb 2024 Interac e-Transfer Receive 250.00    3368.20 CR     3118.2
01 Feb 2024 Water company              33.84     3334.36 CR    3300.52
```

Comment: This looks great!  Rather than eliminate a header to facilitate the data, what I need  now is to figure out how to identify what column should be blank as each row has an item under 'money in' or 'money out' but not both.

Comment: I do not think you have to worry.  Export-CSV will include every column and blank columns will be between two commas.

Comment: Actually the output needs to reflect the 5 headers (Borrowings is missing and that the first line's $1601.87 falls under Money In and the $3490.43 should fall under Borrowings and the money in should be blank. The 2nd line 372.23 falls under money out and money in is blank and borrowings has the total 3118.20. As I mentioned, I need to figure out how to insert a blank in the input file before I run the code.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would simply:

- Concatenate everything to a single line:

```
$OneLine = -Join (Get-Content .\VerticalFile.txt)
```

- Than split the rows based on the commas that are followed ([LookAhead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) by a date string:

```
$Csv = $OneLine -Split ',(?=\d\d ... \d\d\d\d)', [Environment]::NewLine
```

- Optionally, if you need the fields quoted:

```
$Csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen this before. I'll give that a try too. Thanks iRon!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but have my answer as well

```
# Please note this presume we KNOW the following:
# the first 5 lines are headers
# the values comes in groups of 4 lines

# Get content of the file, skip the first 5 lines as they are the headers
$content = Get-Content -Path $FilePath | Select-Object -Skip 5

# set line counter
$LineCount = 1

# Loops the content of the file
# when it returns an object every 4 loops\lines, adds it to the $ResultList array
$ResultList = foreach ($line in $content) {

    # clean line
    $line = $line.trim().TrimEnd(',')

    # depending on the relative line number, execute different operations
    switch ($LineCount) {
        1 {
            # first line
            # Create a new empty pscustomobject
            $obj = [pscustomobject]::new()
            # converting the date in a [datetime] value, so it's much easier to manipulate, order and whatever
            Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value ([datetime]::ParseExact($line, 'dd MMM yyyy', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture))
            break
        }

        2 { 
            Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $line
            break
        }

        3 {
            Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MoneyIn -Value $line
            break
        }

        4 {
            Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MoneyOut -Value $line
            # reset LineCount
            $LineCount = 0
            # returns complete object
            $obj
            break
        }

        5 {
            <# never comes here #>
            # Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Borrowings -Value $line
            break
        }
    }

    $LineCount++
}

# orders the result by the date, using its [datetime] value
$OrderedResults = $ResultList | Sort-Object -Property Date | 
    # the fields selection could be moved in Format-Table or Export-Csv if necessary
    Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = { $_.Date.ToString('dd MMM yyyy') } }, Description, MoneyIn, MoneyOut, Borrowings

$OrderedResults | Format-Table

# add -NoTypeInformation if using using powershell verisons older than 6
$OrderedResults | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFilePath
```